# Is it possible to use SubGit on a subsection of an SVN repository?

Tags: git, svn, subgit

We have an SVN Repository with more than just the software we develop. I'd like to start using Git for just our software changes. Is it possible therefore to just use SubGit with a single directory of the SVN repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If the directory is a project with trunk/branches/tags structure, you
can run

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url <SVN URL of that directory> repo.git
$ subgit install repo.git
```

If the directory has no trunk/branches/tags structure, you can run
use this [EAP build](http://old.subgit.com/interim/R-3044/) (or SubGit 3.0
when it is released) and run

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url <SVN URL of that directory> repo.git
```

Then edit repo.git/subgit/config

to remove all svn.trunk/svn.branches/svn.tags/svn.shelves options and then
run

```
$ subgit install repo.git
```